Derive equation unstable manifold
I am studying the book Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems (third edition) of Perko and in problem set 2.7, Question 4/5 they give the following system:
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1&=-x_1\\
 \dot{x}_2&=-x_2+x_1^2\\
\dot{x}_3&=x_3+x_2^2
\end{align}
Then we have to derive the equations for the stable and unstable manifold using successive approximations. For the stable manifold we use
\begin{align}
U(t) = \begin{pmatrix} e^{-t} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-t} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, V(t) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & e^{t}\end{pmatrix}, G(x_1,x_2)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ x_1^2\\ x_2^2\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
and solve \begin{align}
u^0(t,a)&=(0,0)\\
u^{n+1}(t,a) & = U(t)a+\int_0^tU(t-s)G(u^n(s,a))ds-\int_t^\infty V(t-s)G(u^n(s,a))ds
\end{align}
I understand that, but what about the unstable manifold? What would $U$ and $V$ be?
